# Проблемы с кодировкой данных в сессии

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка, php

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Записываю в сессию строку 'Москва'. Строка в кодировке utf-8.
Когда читаю из сессии, вместо строки 'Москва' получаю строку '1�осква' в кодировке ASCII.
При попытке преобразовать кодировку с помощью функции iconv возвращается пустая строка.
Файл с php скриптом сорханен в кодировке UTF-8 без бум.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.
Заранее спасибо.

По просьбе [[@romeo](/users/10551/romeo)](/users/10551/romeo) привожу упрощенный фрагмент кода

```
session_start();
//mb_detect_encoding('Москва') вернет utf-8
$_SESSION['CITY'] = array(23 => 'Москва', 56 => 'Рим');
session_write_close();
var_dump($_SESSION['CITY'][23]); //Отобразит 1�осква
```

Коллеги приветствую. Наконец дошли руки, что бы отписаться. Проблема была из-за моей невнимательности. Итак причина.

```
$_SESSION['CITY'] = array(23 => 'Москва', 56 => 'Рим'); //Двумерный массив
//Нашел вот такую конструкцию, которая шла после инициализации массива
$_SESSION['CITY'][23]['TEST'] = 1; //Хотя $_SESSION['CITY'] - двумерный массив
```

Comment: А поподробнее?

Comment: Вы не можете получить кириллические символы в "кодировке ASCII".

Comment: Я не могу понять, почему кодировка данных сессии становится ASCII. Как ее можно установить в значение UTF-8?

Comment: @Nicholas Essen,

1. У вас не ASCII. В ASCII только 128 некириллических символов.
2. Кодировка - это не какое-то изменяемое свойство строки. Кодировка - это, если грубо, способ преобразования символов в байты. Она не может поменяться сама собой, только байты могут неправильно записаться.

Comment: Я извиняюсь за невежество. Но как мне избавиться от данной проблемы?

Comment: Вы внося данные в сессию чем-то предварительно их обрабатываете? Если да, то покажите листинг (программный код). Возможно Вам помогут первые два первых пункта указанные [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/386724/html-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=386787#386787).

Comment: @romeo, я добавил проблемный код к вопросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама страница, куда приходит var_dump, тоже в utf-8?

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: Да. По факту проблема решена. Причина невнимательность и попытка php сделать конкатенацию. Мы пытаемся записать что-то в измерение, которого нет, в результате происходит объединение того, что есть в текущем измерении. 
Если прописать:
$_SESSION['CITY'][23]['TEST'] = 2 // получим 2�осква
$_SESSION['CITY'][23]['TEST'] = 3 // получим 3�осква
$_SESSION['CITY'][23]['TEST'] = 4 // получим 4�осква